# Fetch AzureDevops build details by Pull Request

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

My requirement is to tell the user if his/her PR got deployed successfully or not
So I thought,

1. I can ask user about his PR#
2. Using PR# - Fetch Build Details
3. Using BuildID from Step 2, find deployment information

I stuck at step 2
I am using below documentation to fetch build details.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Not able to find correct usage of reasonFilter parameter to pass pull request id to fetch build details
[API URL Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKgZf.png)

[Build Reson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zdmg.png)

Can someone help how exactly to use reasonFilter parameter here
tried this _apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1&$top=1&reasonFilter=pullrequest=20056

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the point you're stuck with: The `reasonFilter` is simply a number of predefined string values you can choose from. For instance, if you specify `reasonFilter=pullrequest`, you get all builds started by a pull request. Thus, you can't specify the exact PR ID here.

Regarding your requirement in general: I don't think there's an API to strictly tie the PR ID and its build(s). You should look into the [Status API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/statuses?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) instead. The build is just one of the statuses that can be associated with the pull request or, more specifically, with the commit.

So, I would approach your task the following way (note that it's not an exact algorithm, but a number of steps I would try to find the solution):

- get the [pull request by the PR ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-request?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) provided by user
- find the `lastMergeCommit` in the response
- get the [statuses of that merge commit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/statuses/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)
- investigate the collection of [`GitStatus` objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/statuses/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#gitstatus) returned back and find out how to filter the build you're looking for (I don't know the format of that response for sure, but I'm confident there's some attribute to judge by)

Hope this can lead you to the right direction.

Comment: I've tried that, but the statuses API returns very random results - never the full list of statuses that i can see on the UI page in AzDO for it.
Maybe someone knows what might be the issue there.

Answer (score 0):

> how exactly to use reasonFilter parameter here tried this _apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1&$top=1&reasonFilter=pullrequest=20056

Based on your requirement, you need to filter the build via build reason and Pull Request ID.

I'm afraid there is no out-of-box parameter to filter by pull request ID in the Rest API.

For a workaround, you can try to add the tag to your build.

Here are the steps:

1. You can add a step in your build to use Pull Request ID as Build tag. Refer to this doc: [AddBuildTag: Add a tag to the build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#addbuildtag-add-a-tag-to-the-build)

For example:

```
- powershell: |
  
   
   Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$env:SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_PULLREQUESTID"
   
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
  condition: eq(variables['Build.reason'], 'pullrequest')
```

You can set the condition to make sure that when the pipeline is triggered by pull request, it will add build tag.

2. You can add the `tagFilters` in Rest API to filter the related build.

For example:

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_apis/build/builds?reasonFilter=pullrequest&tagFilters=PullrequestID&api-version=6.0
```

Comment: It is throwing error while using ]$env:SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_PULLREQUESTID"

Unable to process command '##vso[build.addbuildtag]' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2022-05-25T14:35:23.7122005Z ##[error]Build tag is required.
2022-05-25T14:35:23.9300623Z ##[debug]System.Exception: Build tag is required.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `branchName` URI parameter because pull requests create an internal merge branch every time.

The branch is visible in the `sourceBranch` property of the build and looks like "refs/pull/10797/merge". If you know the pull request ID it's easy to determine the merge branch name and filter by it.